# Weblogic 10 - JSF 2.1 deployment issue

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I have JSF2.0 application with primefaces 7 deployed on weblogic 10.3.6.0, it was working fine but some of primefaces features requires jsf-api-2.1.jar. So we have deployed jsf-api-2. 1. jar as library below

[image]

and addded weblogic.xml into applcation war to refer it as

```
 <library-ref>
     <library-name>jsf</library-name>
     <specification-version>2.1</specification-version>
     <implementation-version>2.1.1-FCS</implementation-version>
     <exact-match>false</exact-match>
 </library-ref>
```

but while deploying war we are getting below error .

[image]

We can place jar in WEB-INF lib and can add tag

```
    <container-descriptor>
       <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>
```

it works but caused issue with other libs . What could be issue , if it is deployed as library why application not able to refer it and getting error during deployment . Is there any way to refer/use jsf-api-2.1.jar instead of JSF2.0.

Comment: Does this help?
https://blogs.oracle.com/jamesbayer/weblogic-server-shared-libraries-ndash-including-jars

Comment: Weblogic 10.3.6 is servlet 2.5 container and JSF2.1 requires a servlet 3.0 container. WHat you are trying to do may not be possible.

Comment: @chadNC jsf2.1 pom is showing support for servlet2.5 . http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/faces/jsf-api/2.1/jsf-api-2.1.pom or may be my understanding is wrong?